# MAX9926 Maximum Variable Reluctance Input Frequency

Tags: frequency, frequency-measurement, rpm

I am planning on using the MAX9926 to read 2 variable reluctance (magnetic pickup) sensors installed in the crankcase of an engine. The sensors will read the teeth of the starting gear to get the RPM of the engine. There are 135 gear teeth on the starting gear and the engine will be rotating at a maximum of 2600 RPM, this should be a maximum frequency of around 5.8khz. It is likely going to be installed on multiple engines so I would expect an overall maximum of 10khz input frequency to be safe.

I cannot find any reference to the maximum input frequency of the MAX9926 in the datasheet. https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9924-MAX9927.pdf

I did see the max slew rate parameter of 2.3 V/µs and the max charge-pump frequency of 1.3 MHz. The MAX9926 has a 5V output, to achieve this output should take 2.174us, a theoretical maximum frequency of around 460khz. I think the charge pump frequency is not important in this question.

Am I safe to assume that the MAX9926 can handle an input frequency of 10khz?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It think it's safe to assume it might work at 10kHz.  The unity GBW is over 1MHz and the Diff Amp is used with unity gain after you test it and get the SNR up to where it needs to be.

The variable reluctance sensor increases amplitude with velocity or RPM. There is an adaptive output offset based on a peak detector output and thus it is the lowest RPM threshold that is affected by noise and hysteresis.

Comment: Thank you, I think with an idle of around 600rpm there will be enough voltage to deal with any noise. I will give it a try.

Comment: it needs to work at the RPM of the starter to start

Comment: This will only be used as indication of RPM, not for any timing or operation of the engine.

Comment: Gotcha...... for that matter ,  that much resolution, you can filter it for a attack/fast decay time of 50 ms using a calibrated 1 shot and LPF.  1shot duration determine full scale calibration.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I will give it a try and see how it works out.